# Android специфический view

Tags: android, xml, view, customview

[image]
Здравствуйте. Как создать такой view на android? Может какая нибудь библиотека?

Comment: А зачем вам custom view, делаете картинки круглые и верстаете, цифры в круге можно вообще на лету подставлять, надписи в textview. Тут вообще ничего специфического не увидел, чего нельзя сделать через готовые вьюшки андроид.

Comment: Думаю что это обычный `RecyclerView`. Картинки с полосками жестко привязаны к смещению, поэтому не съезжают, остальные элементы выставлены относительно этой линии с картинками.

Comment: Можешь это все сверстать в обычном xml без каких-либо библиотек. Потом сделать свою вьюшку которая будет раздувать этот макет. Определить логику внутри этой вью и использовать в разных макетах